# android broadcast receiver & notification

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

hi the below code is the receiver class

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;


public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("the time is right","yay!");
        Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext() , AlarmServie.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

the below code is my service class

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.util.Log;

public class AlarmServie extends Service {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.e("hello","hi" );
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Log.e("onCreate:","came" );
     /*  NotificationManager notifyman = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent main_activity = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent o = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, main_activity, 0);

        /*Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Reminder to Pill")
                .setContentText("Click for info")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(o)v
                .build();*/
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent in = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, in, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(AlarmServie.this);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Pill Reminder");
        mBuilder.setContentText("CLick here to View");
        //mBuilder.setSound(sound);

        TaskStackBuilder ts=TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        ts.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        nm.notify(9999,mBuilder.build());
        return START_STICKY;
    }}
```

the below code is my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />



            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <receiver
                  android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
                  android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".Set">

        </activity><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
     App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


            <service
                android:name=".AlarmServie"
                android:enabled="true"/>




    </application>

</manifest>
```

i used a textbox and a timer button to get text and time from user and saved it in database.when the time in db and system time matches notification must come but it is not coming can anyone say why this happens.clearly explain y this happens by explaining in detail with code

this is my main activity

```
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Sqlitedb dbobj1;
    int gh;
    AlarmManager am;


    Calendar c;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        dbobj1 = new Sqlitedb(MainActivity.this);
        gh = (int) dbobj1.number();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Set.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        Intent my_intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmServie.class);


        am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Date dt = new Date();
        int hour=dt.getHours();
        int min=dt.getMinutes();
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, my_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Cursor t = dbobj1.recenttime(hour,min);
        t.moveToFirst();
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, t.getInt(0));
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, t.getInt(1));
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pi);


        populate();

    }
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        //client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    //oncreate ends here


    class customAdabter extends ArrayAdapter<setget> {
        Context _context;
        List<setget> _li;

        public customAdabter(Context con, int layout, List<setget> li) {
            super(con, layout, li);
            _context = con;
            _li = li;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            gh++;
            LayoutInflater layu = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View v = layu.inflate(R.layout.item, null);


            TextView txt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_textview1);
            TextView txt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_textview2);
            Button btt = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.item_button1);
            btt.setId(gh);

            btt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int r = v.getId();
                    dbobj1.deleteRow(r);

                    populate();

                }
            });

            setget dataobj = _li.get(position);

            txt.setText(dataobj.getPn());
            txt1.setText(dataobj.getPt());

            return v;
        }
    }


    public void populate() {
        List<setget> li = new ArrayList<setget>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= dbobj1.number(); i++) {
            setget obj = new setget();
            Cursor c = dbobj1.getRow(i);
            String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("pillname"));
            String time = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("pilltime"));
            obj.setPn(name);
            obj.setPt(time);
            c.close();
            li.add(obj);
        }
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        customAdabter customobj = new customAdabter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item, li);
        lv.setAdapter(customobj);

    }
}
```

this is the logcat

```
09-19 11:30:32.267 19426-19426/com.example.ashwin.pillreminder11 D/ActivityThread: BDC-Calling onReceive: intent=Intent { flg=0x114 cmp=com.example.ashwin.pillreminder11/.AlarmReceiver (has extras) }, receiver=com.example.ashwin.pillreminder11.AlarmReceiver@d5ea50b

09-19 11:30:32.267 19426-19426/com.example.ashwin.pillreminder11 E/the time is right: yay!

09-19 11:30:32.268 19426-19426/com.example.ashwin.pillreminder11 D/ActivityThread: BDC-RECEIVER handled : 0 / ReceiverData{intent=Intent { flg=0x114 cmp=com.example.ashwin.pillreminder11/.AlarmReceiver (has extras) } packageName=com.example.ashwin.pillreminder11 resultCode=0 resultData=null resultExtras=null}
```

Comment: @Mike M. both notification and alarm is not coming.can u say why this happens....

Comment: @Mike M. yes i am not seeing the log in output.what should i do now.can u explain it with code

Comment: @Mike M. i have updated my code check it

Comment: @Mike M.i tried that too but its not working.any other way

Comment: @Mike M.but it is not a problem the service is not called after calling it only the notification comes

Comment: @Mike M.i got the log from receiver class but i am not receiving the log from service class

Comment: @Aniruddha see i have updated my logcat output also please help me how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<receiver
        android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

change it to

```
<receiver
      android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
      android:enabled="true">
</receiver>
```

and use different broadcast receiver to receive BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast and reset all alarms.

Comment: the problem is the receiver class is not moving to service class

Comment: Provide logcat output

Comment: E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!